# C# retrieve username upon page load

Tags: c#, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i want to retrieve the user's name that the user use after he arrived a the home page upon login. However, im using bootstrap, so im very confused on how to do it.
[Below is the Bootstrap that i need to retrieve the user's name and display in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD1MT.png)

[This is the display that the bootstrap show right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLMU.png)

Comment: Dear Jia Hao,

Please clarify that you using MVC or Webforms?

Comment: Please post code as code, not as pictures.  Can you also please share what you have tried so far? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Im using webforms.

Comment: i tried removing the img src and replace it with <asp:label runat="server" id="namelb">name</label> and it worked. But i need help with retrieve the user's name and change the label to the user's